# Why isn't my return statement working?

Tags: function, python-3.x, binary, converters

I have a function that converts a decimal value to binary. I understand I have the logic correct as I can get it to work outside of a function.

```
def decimaltobinary(value):
    invertedbinary = []
    value = int(value)
    while value >= 1:
        value = (value / 2)
        invertedbinary.append(value)
        value = int(value)
    for n, i in enumerate(invertedbinary):
        if (round(i) == i):
            invertedbinary[n] = 0
        else:
            invertedbinary[n] = 1
    invertedbinary.reverse()
    value = ''.join(str(e) for e in invertedbinary)
    return value

decimaltobinary(firstvalue)
print (firstvalue)
decimaltobinary(secondvalue)
print (secondvalue)
```

Let's say `firstvalue = 5` and `secondvalue = 10`. The values returned each time the function is executed should be `101` and `1010` respectively. However, the values I get printed are the starting values of five and ten. Why is this happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code **works as expected**, but you didn't *assign* the `return`ed value:

```
>>> firstvalue = decimaltobinary(5)
>>> firstvalue
'101'
```

Note that there are easier ways to accomplish your goal:

```
>>> str(bin(5))[2:]
'101'
 >>> "{0:b}".format(10)
'1010'
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help, it's much appreciated. I understand there is an easier way for binary conversion however I wanted to use this method to help ensure that I understand the algorithm for the conversion.